# How to close a file in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, file

I´m trying to store some data in a file. I open the file the first iteration, and add the info. But, when the algorithm end, file size is 5kbs, it must be like 2,5 Mbs.

```
if (!isopen)
{
    NSArray *paths;
    paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    // Check DD
    if ([paths count] > 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"Found a path");
        fichero2 = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"out2.raw"];

        NSLog(@"path %@",fichero2);
    } else {
        //d'oh, something went really wrong
        NSLog(@"ERROR: could not open %s\n", "out.raw");
        return -1;
    }
    isopen = 1;
}
else 
{   
    // Write file
    NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:1152*2];
    [data appendBytes:((SInt16 *)[audioProcessor audioBuffer].mData) length:1152*2];
    [data writeToFile:fichero2 atomically:YES]; 
}
```

Is really need to close the file? It auto close itself? So, why data is not stored?

Comment: Please clean up your code... multi language comments and old dead code read rather badly. Also, it seems impossible to follow the logic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are creating a new NSData each loop,

Should be outside the dope of the iteration, no?

```
 NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:1152*2];
```

then for

```
      [data appendBytes:((SInt16 *)[audioProcessor audioBuffer].mData) length:1152*2];
      [data writeToFile:fichero2 atomically:YES];
```